# Spring Security: Access is Denied Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to configure Spring Security with `LDAP` using OpenLDAP server, I am configuring it to be redirected to my own `LoginController` when the user open the application. However every time it I try to connect to the application it throws an AccessDeniedException, it never enters my `LoginController`

Here is my configuration:

```
<bean name="/login" class="controller.LoginController" />

<s:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com" />

<s:http pattern="/login*" security="none" />
<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <s:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
    <s:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
</s:http>

<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people" />
</s:authentication-manager>
```

And here is my `LoginController`

```
public class LoginController extends AbstractController {

  @Override
  protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ModelAndView("LOGIN");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have access to ldap server anonymously, because you not specified an account to connect, like in this sample:

```
<security:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:10389/o=mojo" 
       manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system"    manager-password="secret" />
```

Here is a good tutorial to make ldap authentication correctly: http://krams915.blogspot.ru/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but is not the account will be provided by the user who will login by providing his username and password ?

Comment: To authenticate this account you will need (probably) another one, used to connect to ldap server. To check it - connect to ldap server manually with some ldap browser like http://jxplorer.org/